# Different textcolors in the same textview

Tags: android, textview, textcolor

in my application i have to show some informations.i would structured these informations like this

`Battery level //red textcolor
80% // black textcolor`

Is it possible? Because for now i have created two separated textview; one for the "title" and another for the information with different colors. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spannable to achieve what you want:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
String text = "<font color='red'>Battery level</font> <font color='black'>80%</font>"
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: In this way have i to create the textview in the xml or not?

Comment: Yes, you would have to create a TextView in the xml file where you define your layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SpannableString` to overcome your issue.

Here is what you can do with your `textviews`

```
TextView tc_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signup_TC_text);

SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Points are awarded when you confirm your email. By signing up, you agree to our Terms & Conditions.");

text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, 80, 0);

final Context context = this;
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    };
    text.setSpan(clickableSpan, 80, 98, 0);

// make our ClickableSpans and URLSpans work
tc_text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

// shove our styled text into the TextView
tc_text.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Here what I have done is, I have counted number of characters from where to where I want some particular color.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: so, i can do something like: `TextView infosTXT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infos_text); SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Battery level: 80%");

text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 13, 0);text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 13, 18, 0);`?

Comment: Yes, try it. Check it on the device.